# How to delete all rows of section in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a code where I have to  insert & delete all rows on selecting a section.

Below is the code for inserting & deleting

```
var paths = [IndexPath]()
for row in 0..<(arrayOfSection?.count)! {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: selectedIndex!)
    paths.append(indexPath)
}

// Toggle collapse
if previousSelectedIndex != nil && previousSelectedIndex == section {

    self.arrayOfCategories?.removeAll()
    self.catergoryTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.catergoryTableView.deleteRows(at: paths, with: .fade)
    self.catergoryTableView.endUpdates()
}
else{
    self.catergoryTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.catergoryTableView.insertRows(at: paths, with: .fade)
    self.catergoryTableView.endUpdates()
    header.setCollapsed(false)
    //scroll
    let sectionRect = self.catergoryTableView.rect(forSection: selectedIndex!)
    self.catergoryTableView.scrollRectToVisible(sectionRect, animated: true)
}

previousSelectedIndex = selectedIndex
```

Inserting rows works fine but when I am trying to delete rows from selected section in am getting below error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 9 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated but – as always –  `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` have no effect at all for a single inert/move/delete operation. You have to insert / delete the corresponding item in the data source before calling `insertRows/deleteRows`

Comment: If you remove your data source, you cannot insert, delete rows one at a time. Either reload table or delete the datasource at the appropriate index one at a time.

Comment: You should try by removing following code `self.arrayOfCategories?.removeAll()`.

Comment: Are you trying to expand and collapse rows on section clicked ?

Comment: You can delete the whole section if thats what you want https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614922-deletesections

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to delete all row as follows:

```
self.catergoryTableView.beginUpdates()
self.catergoryTableView.deleteRows(at: paths, with: .fade)
self.catergoryTableView.endUpdates()
self.arrayOfCategories?.removeAll()
```

Just add first line of code to the last.